# Wpf datagrid update datacontext on datagrid cell value changed

Tags: .net, wpf

I have `DataGrid`, user editable, when user edit cell, I want to datacontext to change. How can I do it?

```
<my:DataGrid Height="279" Name="dataGrid1" Width="210" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Props}" CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding">
    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                    <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" ></my:DataGridTextColumn>
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

```
class ConfigModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Prop> props;

    public ObservableCollection<Prop> Props
    {
        get { return props; }
        set { props = value; OnPropertyChanged("Props"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string Props)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Props));
    }
}


public class Prop {
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private string value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeConfiguration();            
    }

    private void InitializeConfiguration(){
        var conf = new ObservableCollection<Prop>();
        conf.Add(new Prop() { Name = "path", Value = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["path"].DefaultValue.ToString() });
        conf.Add(new Prop(){ Name = "host", Value = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["host"].DefaultValue.ToString()});
        DataContext = new ConfigModel() { Props = conf };
    }
```

Comment: How do you want the `DataContext` to change? And why?

Comment: To change values, in collection

Comment: The `DataGrid` changes the data in `DataContext` when user edits it. Or do you want to change some other data? If that's the case, could you post an example or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: ou, thx, didnt know. i really wanted to change collection in datacontext. thx, but why my onpropertychanged doesnt fire?

Comment: That would fire only if you (or someone else, like the `DataGrid`) added, removed or replaced an item in the collection. If you are only editing existing items, that setter will never be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **PropertyChanged** event on your collection is **raised when the collection changes** (e.g., items are added or removed), but not when a **property of one of the items** (of type Prop in your example) changes. For that you will **need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged** on your **Prop class**.